# # of ways to place books on shelf

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This is a question about the the # of ways I can place the books on shelves.

I have to place a book on n number of shelves with m number of books; m >= n >= 1.

But I have to have atleast 1 book on each shelf.

I know with

$$\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot \ldots \cdot  (n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)\cdot ... \cdot (n+m-1)}{ 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot ...\cdot (n-2)\cdot (n-1)}=\frac{(n+m-1)! }{ (n-1)!}$$

it has every combination of ways to place the books on the shelves, but it also has the possibility of leaving a shelf empty, which does not satisfy having atleast 1 book on each shelf.

So I am wondering, what do I have to do to have the correct equation that satisfies having 1 book on each shelf.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not calculate the number of possible solutions that have empty shelves (using the same method) and subtract that?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:  Start by putting placeholders where the books are going to go.  Do this in two steps.  First, put a placeholder on each shelf.  Second, count the number of ways of putting the remaining $m-n$ placeholders on the shelves.

When you're done, assign the $m$ books to the placeholders.