# Combinatorics: ways to place books

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So we're trying to partition {1..n} into m ordered sets.
I would do this by first scrambling {1..n} into one of n! orderings.
After having done that we can partition that into m non-empty sets in (n−1m−1) ways.
Now we have a sorted partition into m sorted sets, but we want an unsorted one. So we divide out by the number of possible orderings of the shelves, m!
This gives us a total of
n!m!(n−1m−1)
ways to shelve these books.

If any of the steps are unclear, I can add more explanation.

Comment: Are the shelves identical?

Comment: Yes they are identical

Comment: Instead of putting up a new posting, it would have been better to edit the version from the other day, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942915/of-ways-to-place-books-on-shelf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we're trying to partition $\{1..n\}$ into $m$ ordered sets.
I would do this by first scrambling $\{1..n\}$ into one of $n!$ orderings.
After having done that we can partition that into $m$ non-empty sets in $n-1 \choose m-1$ ways.
Now we have a **sorted** partition into $m$ sorted sets, but we want an unsorted one. So we divide out by the number of possible orderings of the shelves, $m!$
This gives us a total of $$\frac{n!}{m!}{n-1 \choose m-1}$$ ways to shelve these books.

If any of the steps are unclear, I can add more explanation.

Comment: hey, i have a question on how to solve the binomial coefficient?

Comment: Do you mean how I chose the top and bottom parts for this problem in particular? Or is it a general question about binomial coefficients? In the latter case it might be worthwhile to open a new question so that others can benefit from it too.